# Decrypt OpenSSL Bruteforce

Tags: encryption, openssl, bitcoin, brute-force

I forgot the password to my bitcoin backup and would like to brute-force decrypt it. 
I have been given this information; 
"The manual backup files are encrypted using your chosen backup password. You can use OpenSSL to            decrypt:

```
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in <filename>"
```

Unfortunately, I don't have much experience doing this and all I can do it get it in terminal asking for the password. Can anybody give me instructions on how to brute-force decrypt a file using OpenSSL?

n.b. The password was quite simple, using only letters and perhaps one number.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about brute-forcing a password for a command-line tool.

Comment: Hi, do you mean I have posted it to the wrong place?

Comment: Yes, I don't think this is on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: OK. Do you have any suggestions for where I might be able to find an answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> ... all I can do it get it in terminal asking for the password.

You need to add `-passin pass:XXX` options, where XXX is the password you want to try.

There's more options for `-passin`, see [PASS PHRASE ARGUMENTS](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) for [`openssl(1)`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/openssl.html) command.

You will also need to understand the `-k` and `-K` options to `openssl enc`.

---

> Can anybody give me instructions on how to brute-force decrypt a file using OpenSSL?

Run something like this in a loop:

```
# Build your list of candidates
PASSWORDS=...

for PASSWORD in $PASSWORDS; do

  openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in <filename> -passin pass:$PASSWORD 
  RET=$?

  if [ $RET -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Candidate password: $PASSWORD"
  fi

done
```

`openssl enc` returns 0 on success, non-zero otherwise. *Note*: you will get false positives because AES/CBC can only determine if "decryption works" based on getting the padding right. If the file decrypts but is ***not*** recovered, then remove that candidate password.

Authenticated encryption would fix the ambiguity, but you would have needed to encrypt with AES/CCM, AES/GCM, AES/EAX etc.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to try on your own there is now a bruteforcing tool that will do it very efficiently, called bruteforce-salted-openssl. Note that the digest used back in the days by openssl was md5 (rather than sha256 today), so you would have to specify the digest (-m md5)

Comment: Also openssl encryption now used pbkdf2 (iterative password hashing), however it does not store the number of iterations in the file being decrypted, and the default count (10000) is generally regarded as far far too small.   Really brute forcing new openssl encrypted files is VERY slow if you even know the iteration count needed.